# PS - How to save output to file with colors?

Tags: powershell

How can I save the terminal output to a PDF file with colors?

I use right now this command:

`myCommand that output something with colors to terminal | Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft Print to PDF"`

It does create the file, but colors are missing. Any ideas? Tips?

I'm using Windows 10, Powershell

Comment: Out-Printer is just going to take the basic data in the given object and pass it on to the defined printer. Any colourisation in the console is just an instruction to the console to make it appear that way. I highly doubt that this can be passed to PDF in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily suggest using a module for doing that, gives you more control over the output most of the times.

http://www.powertheshell.com/modules/

Get the PDFTools Mod.

```
Out-PTSPdf -Name "YourFileName" -Path C:\Users\YourUser\Documents
```

Nevertheless, I doubt that PowerShell actually pipes "colored content" with colors, because it is the PowerShell Engine itself "coloring" according to the syntax. Not sure about that tho.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how your output commands look like, but ...
You could create an html file with colours and print this file as PDF, e.g.:

```
$HTMLFilePrefix = "<head></head><body>"
$HTMLFileSuffix = "<body>"
$HTMLStartRed = "<p><span style='color:red'>"
$HTMLEndRed = "</span></p>"
$HTMLFilePrefix + $HTMLStartRed + "This text is colored red" + $HTMLEndRed + $HTMLFileSuffix | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.htm"
```

Maybe "ConvertTo-Html" can also help to create the html file ...

Answer (score 0):

If you run your script in Windows Terminal Preview you can copy and paste the output (into Word for example) and it will preserve all the formatting.